Encountering cert errors on deploying spring boot based kafka consumer application on weblogic server
I have created a Spring Boot application to consume messages from a Kafka topic using Avro schema. The application works fine on my local machine and also runs successfully on a Linux server when I execute it using "java -jar application.war".
However, when I deploy the WAR package on the WebLogic server, it throws the following errors.
24-08-21 10:45:00.665 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] ERROR o.s.k.listener.LoggingErrorHandler - Error while processing: null
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition PKY.Organization.openingShop.topic.public.any.v2-1 at offset 4130208. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema for id 729
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:377)

I have already set the correct keystore path on the server.
Could anyone please guide me on what changes I need to make at the code level or the WebLogic configuration level to resolve this issue?
Spring boot version 2.4.13.
Weblogic version: 12.2.1c
Java version: "1.8.0_412"
I am including some important code snippets below for reference.
Configuration.java
public ConsumerFactory<KeySchema, CountryShop> consumerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        
        Map<String,Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put("bootstrap.servers","rp-dkxn-qi-akz-qq-os:9080");
        config.put("sasl.mechanism","SCRAM-SHA-256");
        config.put("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
        config.put("ssl.truststore.location", "/u02/oracle/certs/truststore.jks");
        config.put("ssl.truststore.password", "**********");
        config.put("sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"pp.countryShop.v1\" password=\"*************************\";");
        config.put("schema.registry.url", "https://mq-us-ap-uu-xc-dk-ia:8081");
        config.put("schema.registry.ssl.truststore.location", "/u02/oracle/certs/truststore.jks");
        config.put("schema.registry.ssl.truststore.password", "**********");
        config.put("schema.registry.ssl.keystore.location", "/u02/oracle/certs/keystore.jks");
        config.put("schema.registry.ssl.keystore.password", "***************");

        config.put("group.id", "PKY.schedule.PKYDev.consumerGroup.v1");
        config.put("key.deserializer", KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
        config.put("value.deserializer", KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
        config.put("auto.register.schemas", false);
        config.put("specific.avro.reader", true);
        config.put("use.latest.version", true);

I have changed the some name for security purposes.
pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.13</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.maersk</groupId>
    <artifactId>CountryShopListener</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Emp_gsisListener</name>
    <description>Consuming message from GSIS</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.countryShop.countryShopListener</start-class>
        <confluent.version>5.5.0</confluent.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <url>https://packages.confluent.io/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-config</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-utils</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--Add this block : Start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--Add this block : End -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <mainClass>com.CountryShop</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


I have also added the certificate detail in weblogic startup Java argument
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/u02/oracle/certs/truststore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=*****************
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/u02/oracle/certs/keystore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=*******************

Please suggest How can I resolve the error encountering after deploying application on weblogic server.
I had tried many configuration change.
1- Tried by adding custom Identity keystore and truststore on weblogic console keystore and ssl.-- It throw Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
2- Define config.java file info on application.yml file as well.
3- tried by importing schema registry public certificate in JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts.-- It throw Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
I appreciate your suggestion to resolve this issue.
